# Is there any code for the stream2 or stream3 function?

Tags: c++, matlab

I want to replicate the functionality of the `stream2` MATLAB function on C++. That is, applying gradient descent over a potential from a given point to a minimum. I have been trying to implement the Sobel operator but when I reach a border (in which the value of my potential is infinite) the Sobel operator fails.

However, using the same pontential with the `stream2` matlab function, the path is correctly computed. Can anybody tell me where to find such implementation in C++ or the theory behind that function?

Comment: Is [this class](http://folk.uib.no/fcihh/thesis/d.ps) applicable? Also have a look at [CGAL (Computational Geometry Algorithms Library)](https://www.cgal.org/).

Comment: @chappjc thank you for the references. I will take a deep look to that. The class SLTracer will not be directly applicable because of my data type (I'm working with a flat vector) but looks nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to implement it by myself. I was mistaken because I was actually not implementing a proper gradient descent.

Now I implemented it following Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent
and the resulting code is here https://github.com/jvgomez/fastmarching/tree/master/gradientdescent